# Does $E(X|\min(X,k))$ converges to $X$ in $L^1$ or almost surely or neither?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-probability

$P(X=k)=1/(2^k)$, $k=1,2,3... ~~~ Y_k=E(X|\min(X,k))$

Does $Y_k$ converges to $X$ in $L^1$ or almost surely or neither? Can somebody give a proof?

Answer (score 2):

For every integrable random variable $X$ and every real number $x$ such that $P[X\geqslant x]\ne0$,
$$
E[X\mid\min(X,x)]=X\,\mathbf 1_{X\lt x}+E[X\mid X\geqslant x]\,\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant x}.
$$

Comment: How to prove the formula, you wrote?

Comment: @3dok The RHS is a function of $\min(X,x)$ which has the correct expectation on every event in the sigma-algebra generated by $\min(X,x)$.